# How to pass object as JSON to a POST or PUT request in grails

Tags: rest, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-2.4

I am using restful service in grails. I have 2 classes `Person`

```
import grails.rest.Resource
@Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])

class Person {
   String name 
   Address address 

    static constraints = {
             }
           }
```

and `Address` as

```
  import grails.rest.Resource
  @Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])
  class Address {

    String house
    static constraints = {
    }
  }
```

and in bootstrap I could create new person entry as follows

```
new Person(name:"John" , address: new Address(house:"John Villa").save()).save();
```

but the problem is I want to do the same thing using a POST request with JSON data. 
I set the UrlMappings.Groovy like

```
"/app/person"(resources: "person",  includes: ['index', 'show', 'save', 'update', 'delete', 'create', 'patch'])

"/app/address"(resources: "address",  includes: ['index', 'show', 'save', 'update', 'delete', 'create', 'patch'])
```

then I tried using POSTMAN rest client by sending a POST request to '/app/person'  with JSON data

```
{
   "name":"john" ,
   "address": "{'house' :'sample address' }"
}
```

but it gives error 422 unprocessable entity.

How can I do the same using JSON ? I want to do both insertion and updation using POST and PUT methods.

Comment: could you show me source of your /app/person/index controller?

Comment: I don't have a controller called PersonController.   crud operations on Person objects are automatically set by grails when I use `"/app/person"(resources: "person")` this url mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the JSON you are sending. While it's valid JSON it's not the correct representation for your resource. Your JSON should be:

```
{
   "name":"john",
   "address": 
   {
      "house":"sample address"
   }
}
```

As you can see from the above that the `address` property is actually a nested object and not a `String` like you are sending.

Comment: I tried with this format. but doesn't work. [this is thre response i'm getting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ1tb.png).

Answer (score 0):

Moreover did you check guides on http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html ?
Especially I would like you to check section:

```
grails.mime.types = [
    …
    json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
    …
    xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]
```

Remember that when you process '*/app/person*' with *PersonInstance*, you in fact execute '*/app/person/index/*' with *PersonInstance* (so debug it's source if needed).

Also double check '*id*' column in your classes.